# Postgres comparing strings from json and table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, where-clause, stored-functions

I have the following postgres stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wg.get_user(
    req jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    user_email VARCHAR;
    resp JSONB;
BEGIN
    user_email := req->'email';
    raise notice '(%)', user_email;
    SELECT row_to_json(t) INTO resp FROM (
        SELECT email, name, default_project_id
        FROM wg.users
        WHERE (email = user_email)
    ) t;
    RETURN resp;
END;

$BODY$;
```

I call this with:

select wg.get_user( '{ "email": "x@x" }'::jsonb);

and I have a row with 'x@x' in the email column, defined as VARCHAR(100).  The following SQL returns my row:

```
    SELECT email, name, default_project_id
    FROM wg.users
    WHERE email = 'x@x'
```

The notice call within the stored function returns:

NOTICE:  ("x@x")

However, The function is returning NULL because apparently the WHERE clause does not match, even though both seem to evaluate as "x@x".

It works if I change the comparison to inequality (email > user_email works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you need to extract the email *as text*, like so:

```
user_email := req ->> 'email';
```

`->` extracts a *json string*, so for your sample data this yields: `"x@x"`.

On the other hand, `->>` extracts the data as text, which produce `x@x`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I hadn't noticed that the JSON strings still had quotes around them!